# Alternative synonyms for "My Stuff"

Tags: accounts, profile, user-profile, synonyms

Are there any good alternatives/synonyms for a menu item where the user can access their "stuff" or personal items? Not only their settings and personal data, but also their items, favourites, own products and things like that. Something else than "Profile" or "Account" or "My Stuff".

For instance, if this was for a game, where you collect "Items", "Characters", "Active Games", "Friends"... You would access them there, besides your user data.

---

To clarify a bit more without revealing too much confidential stuff about the application, it's the place for accessing not only personal settings, but also one's collection of different kinds of items. And it ought to sound a little more fun and less stuffy.

I found two sets of alternatives:

STUFFY: 
 - Collection
 - Register
 - Directory

FUN: 
 - Stash
 - Hoard
 - Trove

Comment: This possibly falls under the "_I'm having trouble coming up with a good icon for feature X. Should I ask here for ideas?_" example of off-topic-ness... if it doesn't, it may help if you **(a)** add some details about your specific app (if you have one) and **(b)** add what you don't like about the "standard" terms, or why they don't fit the use-case you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If this menu item contains all the items relating to the user, then you can give the menu item the name of the actual user (and even the profile image if you have one). The other categories could then be displayed as a sub-menu of this menu item. Make sure you provide affordance that this is a clickable menu item (e.g. in the screenshot below there is an arrow to show that there is a sub-menu).

[image: menu screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! But I am looking for a single term for different kinds of items.

Answer (score 1):

In game oriented UIs, the set of things that the user "carries with them" throughout the experience often referred to as a **backpack**.

Comment: I like that! It's some kind of container in any case. Like a capsule or something...

Comment: The context of our app is sciency & biological, so I could call it "My pouch" or "My vat" or something. Or perhaps "My vessel". Or maybe "Your..." ...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on content, you can use:

• Favorites

• Star or heart icons

• My Apps

• Frequently used

• Top *****